# State of checkbox lost after postback in a custom template field

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, viewstate, templatefield, itemplate

I have created a custom checkbox template field by deriving it from System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField. The template for this field has been created by creating a class which implements ITemplate interface. When any postback happens on the page the values in the checkboxes is lost.

To get this working temporarily I have used viewstate to store the state of checkboxes in the checkbox column, but going further I want to completely avoid this as I will be using more template fields in same fashion in my application.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Following is the code:

```
namespace MyControls
{
    public class CheckBoxTemplateField : TemplateField
    {
        public CheckBoxTemplateField()
        {
            this.HeaderTemplate = new CheckBoxTemplate();
            this.ItemTemplate = new CheckBoxTemplate();
        }
    }

    public class CheckBoxTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            container.Controls.Add(chk);
        }
    }
}
```

Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: I actually just discovered that doing what you've done here - deriving from TemplateField and setting the ItemTemplate in the constructor - is the only way to get a TemplateField column to properly persist on postback.  I'd have to see the rest of your code to work out why you're losing the checkbox state though, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

checkbox is known with their problem maintaining their value in postback

1 solution is to store its value in hidden fiesld and to read it in server.

*p.s. thhis has nothing to do with viewstate.input control doesnt saves their value in viewstate ( excpet textbox which has the 'ontextchange' event)*

Comment: Hidden field or viewstate is similar thing. I don't want to do it manually because the problem is not limited to checkbox, I have to use different types of template fields in future which may contain dropdowns etc.